# White edge around objects because of Depth of Field - Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, depth-of-field

This white fringe very often appears in my renders. This began after Eevee's depth of field rework in one of the latest patches. I have this fringe both in blender 2.93 and 2.93.5. The white edge is visible in the viewport and final render.

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: EEVEE is not a great render engine for DOF - It has to drop resolution to maintain performance, as well as having a number of other limitations that can make an artifact-free scene difficult to achieve - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html#eevee-limitations-dof

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.